# How to graph the inverse trigonometric function (arctan, arccotan) in asymptote?

Tags: graphs, asymptote

A want to add the inverse trig.function for tangens to the code of asymptote. Thank you for adivise.

```
settings.outformat="pdf";
unitsize(2.5cm);
import graph;
     
real xmin = -pi/2;
real xmax = pi/2;
real ymin = -pi/2;
real ymax = pi/2;

xlimits(xmin,xmax);
ylimits(ymin,ymax);

//axis and the grid :

xaxis(Label("$x$",align=2E),Ticks("$%.2f$",new real[]{xmin,-1,1,xmax},Size=1mm,1bp),Arrow);
yaxis(Label("$y$",align=2N),Ticks("$%.2f$",new real[]{xmin,-1,1,xmax},Size=1mm,1bp),Arrow);

// function y=sin(x)
    real f(real x) {return sin(x)/cos(x); }
    path g = graph(f,xmin+0.5, xmax-0.5);
    draw(g,red,
        L= Label("$y=tan(x)$", UnFill,          
        position=EndPoint));
    
// function y=x
    draw((xmin-0.25,ymin-0.25)--(xmax+0.25,ymax+0.25),
        L= Label("$y=x$", UnFill,position=EndPoint));
```

[image: Image of trigonometric cotg and its inverse arccotg functions]

Comment: What is your desired image?

Comment: `atan` for arctangent in radians, `aTan` for degrees. See https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/doc/Mathematical-functions.html#Mathematical-functions. You can compute arccotan from arctan.

Comment: Please [edit] your original post.  Don't post updates as answers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The graph and its inverse are symmetric to the bisector `y=x`, so one way is rotate it to x-axis, reflex to y-axis, then rotate back, and we get the graph of the inverse. This way `rotate(45)*yscale(-1)*rotate(-45)` works for any curve. `// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(1cm);
import graph;
import math;
axes("$x$","$y$");
drawline((0,0),(1,1),gray+.3pt);

real dx=.35;
path g = graph(tan,-pi/2+dx, pi/2-dx);
draw(g,red);
draw(rotate(45)*yscale(-1)*rotate(-45)*g,blue);`

Comment: this is for `arccotan` graph `unitsize(1cm);
import graph;
import math;
drawline((0,0),(1,1),gray+.3pt);
drawline((0,pi),(1,pi),gray+dashed);
drawline((pi,0),(pi,1),gray+dashed);
axes("$x$","$y$");
real f(real x) {return 1/tan(x);}
real dx=.25;
path g = graph(f,dx, pi-dx);
draw(g,red);
draw(rotate(45)*yscale(-1)*rotate(-45)*g,blue); `

Answer (score 1):

The general idea for drawing an inverse is to plot `(f(x),x)` in some manner.  With the cotangent of your image, that would mean changing your code to

```asy
real xmin = 0;
real xmax = pi;
real ymin = -pi/2;
real ymax = pi/2;
...
real f(real x) {return cos(x)/sin(x); }
```

and then adding at the end:

```asy
pair h(real t) { return (f(t),t); }
path j = graph(h,xmin+0.3,xmax-0.3);
draw(j,blue,L=Label("$y=cotg^{-1}(x)$", UnFill,
    position=EndPoint));
```

Resulting in:

[image: output]